# Change Images on update page CMS

Tags: php, html, image-upload

Well this is the only problem that bugs me a lot every time I create a CMS.
Say I have included the functionality to add some images with text (Not a image gallery) . This is the create function of CRUD. The read and delete are also not very difficult. The only problem I face is with the **update** function.

How should the image update be handled. How can I know that if the user wants to change the image and later if he submits a new image.

If he checks to change the image and uses the same image to upload, it would be useless to first unlink the previous image and upload the same image again.

How are these kind of things handled?

At this moment I am using codeigniter for Development.

Answer (score 0):

Most CMS's will have image functionality baked in. I'd first suggest not trying to reinvent the wheel here.

In ExpressionEngine for example (on a codeigniter backend) you're givin a 'field tag' `<img src="{{channel.img}}" />`

The CMS is smart enough on the backend to change that field's value on update without you having to manually do anything. The only issue is if it overwrites the image name/location rather than created a new image in the uploads and leaving the previous one in there.

This is how it's handled in Umbraco CMS as well.

What else do you need?